# Unhandled exception in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I finished writing the program in C++. I used 'cout' for debugging. Everything was working, I deleted the debug comments, but there is a problem with running the program. When I use comments, everything works well. But when I delete them, the program starts, allows me to write file name, but when I press 'enter', the error occures:

**Unhandled exception at 0x0142d866 in Pathfinder.exe: 0xC0000005: Access                   violation reading location 0xcccccc70**

and **xiosbase** header file opens, indicating on

```
fmtflags __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL flags() const
{   // return format flags
    return (_Fmtfl);
}
```

The error occurs when I try to put elements in Map. This happens only when the debug comment is removed in the different function.
Can anyone help?

```
-this 0xcccccc6c {_Stdstr=??? _Mystate=??? _Except=??? ...} const std::ios_base * const
    std::_Iosb<int> {...}   std::_Iosb<int>
    __vfptr CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
    _Stdstr CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
    _Mystate CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated 
    _Except CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
    _Fmtfl  CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
    _Prec   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
    _Wide   CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  
    _Arr    CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
    _Calls  CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
    _Ploc   CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found 
    _Index  0   int
    _Sync   true    bool
```

Comment: I think we may need more information, like stack trace, and a fair portion of your code around the last part that you are sure working.

Comment: We need more code. Show us how you are adding things into the map, and what your debug comment is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value 0xcccccc70 looks like the program uses an offset from an uninitialized pointer.

In debug mode memory is filled with 0xcccccccc to make this more visible.

Comment: But what removing or adding comments can change?

Comment: @giooo: If you're invoking undefined behaviour by corrupting memory, any number of factors can make a difference. Your toolchain is probably producing different code in Release mode, or it could simply be poor luck. The important thing to remember is that when you are corrupting memory, the results are _inherently unpredictable_.

Comment: I agree with @Tomalak.

Changing a comment shouldn't make a difference. If it does, then an uninitialised variable is most likely the cause. It can result in all kinds of crazy, unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: @MRAB: Or a buffer overrun, or dereferencing an invalid pointer, or.... anything else that is named as Undefined Behaviour in the standard.

Comment: But I use map.h. I just write map.put(IntegerToString(i),string); Can that be header files fault?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a real pain to troubleshoot by analyzing code. The others have pointed you out to a good general direction, but if you don't see something obvious like an uninitialized pointer, then it's probably some kind of memory corruption.

[Enable full pageheap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286470) for your program, and then run in the debugger again. It should crash earlier if not at the point of corruption, which will give you more information to go forward with.